# Group dataframe by multiple factors then perform numeric calculation using Tidyverse style

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm trying to get better at using the Tidyverse approach to data wrangling. So I have made a dataframe with 4 columns consisting of three categorical variables and one continuous variable. How can I group on the three categorical variables then calculate the mean, range, IQR, etc. (no particular function) of the values in the fourth *column* containing the continuous variable?
Here is my attempt:

```
col1 <- c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3))
col2 <- c(rep("x", 3), rep("y", 3))
col3 <- c("1", "1", "2", "2", "3", "3")
col4 <- as.numeric(runif(6, min = 0, max = 5))
df <- cbind(col1, col2, col3, col4)
df <- as.data.frame(df)
df$col4 <- as.numeric(df$col4)


df %>%
  filter(col1 == "A") %>%
  filter(col2 == "x") %>%
  filter(col3 == "1") %>%
  summarise(
    maximum = max(col4),
    minimum = min(col4),
    print(maximum - minimum)
  )
```

But I'm fairly certain individuals who are competent with the Tidyverse would consider my attempt very ugly so I would appreciate any input.

Comment: probably do `df %>%filter(col1 == 'A', col2 == 'x', col3 == '1')%>%summarise(...)` without the printing part

Comment: Are you looking for `df %>% group_by(col1, col2, col3) %>% summarise(maximum = max(col4), minimum = min(col4), range = maximum - minimum)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group_by` dplyr function to group by how many rows you want. Then you can use the `summarise` function to create as many summaries as you would like. You may also use the `.groups` argument to control whether you want the outputted tibble to be grouped or not.

```
df |>
  dplyr::group_by(col1, col2, col3) |>
  dplyr::summarise(
    maximum = max(col4),
    minimum = min(col4),
    range = maximum - minimum
  )
```

Also credits for @zephryl for coming up with a very similar answer right before me in the comments.

Comment: This exact answer was given in the comments above. Please double-check all elements of the question before posting, and ensure you credit those who provided the answer first. Thanks

Comment: I just did that @L Tyrone, thanks for letting me know. It was a coincidence since I came up with this answer by myself. Have a nice day!